# how to maintain author name per request in spring and vertx application?

Tags: java, spring, vert.x

I have few microservices written in mainly java( with spring and hibernate). I use vertx for rest apis and for non blocking events.
In every API call there is a jwt token which contains very basic user info like username. I can extract the username from jwt token from vertx RoutingContext.

Now I want to audit the username in database whenever there is change in hibernate entities or when a new entity is getting saved. But after the event is passed to worker verticles that handles the DB operations, I do not have username unless I pass it in eventbus with every request.
I want to know if we can have any context in which I can persist the username and access within worker verticles during the lifecycle of a request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vert.x` is built with async and non blocking paradigm in mind, the separation of contexts is there so no thread sync will be necessary and avoid this overhead

as such, sharing state between workers is not suggested,

I suggest to lean into the message driven domain and have the functions (workers) as pure as possible, i.e pass to each worker all the data he needs to do it's job, send the `username` or/and any other data the worker will need

you don't need to worry much about the event performance, it's very efficient and built for high load

another option will be to use a shared data store, that all workers know and can share the state between them in efficient async way, vert.x has implemented internal `sharedData` and you can use that, although it very basic

so if you need a data store with more capabilities, take a look at `Hazelcast` in memory data grid that can give you a lot more capabilities and still act as a distribute fast and async data store for all nodes, (already plays nicely with `Vert.x` as distribute manger)

Comment: So are you saying something like having separate Context for different verticles and pass the context on every eventbus call? And could you please help me understand how Hazelcast can be useful for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cluster-wide `AsyncMap` to store your data between requests and nodes.

Something like:

```
vertx.sharedData().<String, String>getAsyncMap("mymap", res -> {
  if (res.succeeded()) {
    res.result().put("foo", "bar", resPut -> {...});
  }
});
```

More info [in ref-doc](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_using_the_shareddata_api)

Comment: AsyncMap will be useful if I wanted same information to be shared for all the requests. It is not clear to me how I can store different information( say username)  for every request in AsyncMap.

Comment: you might want to use some unique key to identify each request.. Share some code, so we can better assess what you really want to do